# print the rows that A string(any string) repeats itself 3 times - sed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

F1:

```
abc abc gh abc
abcabc abc
 ab ab cd ab xx ab
ababab cc ababab
abab abab cd abab
```

---

after P1 F1
the output:

```
abc abc gh abc
 ab ab cd ab xx ab
abab abab cd abab
```

Comment: What do you already try ?

Comment: my answered amended and undeleted to correct some code discrepancies..

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner may help:

```
awk '{delete a;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a[$i]++;if(a[$i]>2){print;break}}}' file
```

Comment: `awk '{delete a;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(++a[$i]>2){print;break}}'`

Answer (score 0):

Using awk like this

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){for(var=NF;var>=1;--var){if($var==$i){++mode;}};if(mode>=3){print $0;mode=0;next}else{mode=0;continue}}}'  my_file
```

Comment: my answered amended and undeleted to correct some code discrepancies

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
$ perl -lane '%c=(); for $w (@F) {$c{$w}++}; @a=sort {$a<=>$b} values %c; print $_ if $a[-1]>2 ' file
abc abc gh abc
 ab ab cd ab xx ab
abab abab cd abab
```

Or

```
$ perl -lane '%c=(); for $w (@F) {$c{$w}++; if ($c{$w}>2){print; last}};' file
```